# По разному отображается элемент, сформированный полями

Tags: html, css, scss

Есть такой код `CSS`:

```
i {
    background: $active_blue;
    @include border-radius(10px);
    color: $light_blue;
    font: $main_font;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding:1px 7px 3px;
    display: block;
    top: 26px;
    left: 6px;
}
```

и `HTML` :

```
<i class="count_orders">1</i>
```

Работаю в Мозилле, соответственно форматирую по ней
В реальности это кружочек с цифрой внутри
Но в Мозилле это действительно кружочек, а в Хроме это дыня какая то
Почему так?
Стили сброшены в начале

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Круг должен иметь заданную высоту и ширину, чтобы правильно рассчитывать закругление. Иначе блок может растянуться, и тогда он не будет пропорционален. `padding: n` расширит круг изнутри. Поэкспериментируйте.

Прямой круг получается только с участием этих команд:

```css
i {
  
    /* Важные в закруглении */
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
  
    /* Побочные команды */
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<i class="count_orders">1</i>
```

**ВАЖНО!**

`padding` должен быть одним числом со всех сторон, иначе круг будет не ровным. Либо придется менять `width`, `height` что не совсем правильно.

Ответ примерно таков (из важных свойств):

```
i {
    @include border-radius(50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Везде обязательно использовать фиксированную высоту и ширину, если я использую паддинги?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов ну пропорции должны быть одни и те же. И да использовать фиксированную

Comment: Барабашев нет, не заработало(Падинги убрал и в Хроме цифра подпыгнула вверх

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов ну правильно, без паддинга у тебя у цифры не будет отступа от краев.